# Import error when importing config_util from tensorflow object detection utils

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am importing TF2 config_util from the tensorflow OD github [repo](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/utils/config_util.py)

However this command returns an error that cannot import name 'TensorLike' from 'tensorflow.python.types.core', My tensorflow version is '2.3.2'

```
from object_detection.utils import config_util
```

**Error:**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-46-da187fa0af27> in <module>
----> 1 from object_detection.utils import label_map_util
      2 from object_detection.utils import config_util
      3 from object_detection.utils import visualization_utils as viz_utils

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/object_detection/utils/label_map_util.py in <module>
     25 from six import string_types
     26 from six.moves import range
---> 27 import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
     28 from google.protobuf import text_format
     29 from object_detection.protos import string_int_label_map_pb2

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/_api/v2/compat/__init__.py in <module>
     37 import sys as _sys
     38 
---> 39 from . import v1
     40 from . import v2
     41 from tensorflow.python.compat.compat import forward_compatibility_horizon

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/_api/v2/compat/v1/__init__.py in <module>
     32 from . import autograph
     33 from . import bitwise
---> 34 from . import compat
     35 from . import config
     36 from . import data

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/_api/v2/compat/v1/compat/__init__.py in <module>
     37 import sys as _sys
     38 
---> 39 from . import v1
     40 from . import v2
     41 from tensorflow.python.compat.compat import forward_compatibility_horizon

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/_api/v2/compat/v1/compat/v1/__init__.py in <module>
     79 from tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1 import tpu
     80 from tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1 import train
---> 81 from tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1 import types
     82 from tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1 import user_ops
     83 from tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1 import version

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/_api/v2/compat/v1/types/__init__.py in <module>
     12 import sys as _sys
     13 
---> 14 from . import experimental
     15 
     16 del _print_function

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/_api/v2/compat/v1/types/experimental/__init__.py in <module>
      8 import sys as _sys
      9 
---> 10 from tensorflow.python.types.core import TensorLike
     11 
     12 del _print_function

ImportError: cannot import name 'TensorLike' from 'tensorflow.python.types.core' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/types/core.py)
```

Comment: Did you tried with `TF2.4` ?

Comment: @TFer2, I found the work around, run 1.x code using import tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1 as tf

Answer (score 1):

From comments

> I found the work around, run 1.x code using import
> tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1 as tf (paraphrased from min2bro)